# Excel VBA to search worksheet names and copy a range into active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone please help me with this VBA code? I cannot find out how to search and select worksheets without knowing their names.

I would like to:

1) In my active worksheet, search cell values in range("H6:AW6"), and;

2) If a cell value matches another worksheet name, copy range("C7:C177") from that worksheet and paste it below that cell.

For example, if the cell value H6 of the active worksheet is "Salary" and we have a worksheet named "Salary", I would like a VBA to copy range("C7:C177") of worksheet "Salary" and paste into range("H7:H177") of the active worksheet.

Comment: Does this need to VBA? You could do this with a formula using the `INDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = ws.Range("H6:AW6")

    For Each sh In Sheets
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            If sh.Name = c Then
                sh.Range("C7:C177").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(7, c.Column)
            End If
        Next c
    Next sh


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test() 
    Dim tmpCell As Range 

    For Each tmpCell In ActiveSheet.Range("H6:AW6") 
        On Error Resume Next 
        tmpCell.Offset(1).Resize(171).Value = _ 
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tmpCell.Value).Range("C7:C177").Value 
        On Error GoTo 0 
    Next tmpCell 
End Sub
```